# re.match one from a set of strings, with result as variable

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match a pattern where there may be one of a few strings of characters, and I want to know *which* of those was matched.

So I tried:

```
>>> re.match(r'(test|test2|test3)','test2').group(1)
'test'
```

But I expected the result to be `test2`.

How can I do this, without permitting any string and testing which it was separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First match wins, so order matters:

```
In [2]: re.match(r'(test2|test3|test)','test2').group(1)
Out[2]: 'test2'
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, that actually isn't even an issue for my real implementation - if only I'd been more imaginative than `test[1,2,3]`!

Answer (score 1):

You can generalise this to a helper function that automatically prepares a regex by putting longest matches first and returns a compiled regex ready for use, eg:

```
import re

def match_one_of(*options):
    options = [re.escape(option) for option in options]
    options.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    return re.compile('|'.join(options))

rx = match_one_of('test', 'test2', 'test3')
print rx.match('test2').group()
# test2
```

If you already a list of options, then:

```
options = ['test', 'test2', 'test3']
rx = match_one_of(*options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (^test$|^test1$|^test2$)
```

You can use this.basically add more precision and get the desired result.